# Is it bad practice to reset an error in golang?

Tags: go, error-handling

When parsing a string as text, I want any non-parseable string to result in a zero time and then carry on.

```
passwordLastUsed, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, record[lastUsed])
if err != nil {
    err = nil
    passwordLastUsed = time.Time{}
}
```

This code looks a bit messy and the 'ineffassign' linter returns this for the 'err = nil' statement:

> warning: ineffectual assignment to err (ineffassign)

Is there a better way of handling this or should I just ignore the linter?

Comment: It's probably just saying that you don't use the `err` variable later, after setting it to nil, so you might just as well not make it nil, and only set passwordLastUsed

Comment: To add some context, 'err' is a named return from the function this snippet sits in. I do use it elsewhere in the function and immediately return it when a function it calls doesn't return a non nil value.

Comment: You may use it elsewhere, but you are unconditionally setting it before checking it again--otherwise you wouldn't get that warning.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm only resetting it 'if' the time.Parse function returns an error. If I don't reset it and I reach the final return, I'll return an error to the calling function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not bad practice to reset an error variable, if that's what you want to do.

It is bad practice to set variables that aren't used later--and that's what the warning is about.

There's probably never a reason to reset an error *as you are doing*, since after the `if` block `err` will *always* be `nil`.

It does make sense if you're only resetting in some cases. A common example:

```
result, err := db.Query(...)
if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
    err = nil // Ignore not-found rows
}
if err != nil {
    return err // But return all other errors
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I am using it later, so I think the linter is incorrect in this specific case.

Comment: No, the linter is correct. You may be using it later, but only after it's being unconditionally reset again.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I added another check "if err != nil" immediately after that snippet and it was no longer repeated as ineffectual. As you said, because err was always equal to nil after that piece of code, and the next piece of code reset the value of err, it really was ineffectual.